# Why do we need "alphabets" defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computer-science

I'm reading over my computational theory book before quarter starts and it's giving me the following definitions.

> **alphabet:**
> any nonempty finite set
>
> **symbols:**
> members of the alphabet

I don't understand the relevance of why this term even needs to be defined. It seems unnecessary. What exactly differentiates this from any regular set that has a cardinality greater than 0?

Comment: Nothing but the context in which the term is used. The terminology turns out to be useful, and it’s the terminology that’s being defined here, not the concepts.

Comment: Oh, I see. Contextually useful. Simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: Just as a heads up, there are sets of cardinality strictly greater than zero that are not finite.

Comment: @par: You are quite correct! I should've compared it to a finite set that is not the empty set. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue with forcing. When I started learning about that the term "forcing notion" is just a partial order. Why not use "partial order"? Now I know that when you say "forcing notion" you effectively set the context for using the partial order and it allows you to skip some assumptions on that order (e.g. it has a maximum, the terms "stronger" and "extending", and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in the comments by [Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott):

> Nothing but the context in which the term is used. The terminology turns out to be useful, and it’s the terminology that’s being defined here, not the concepts.